# Installed boto3, pip verified it but keeps saying no module named boto3. Can you light the way?

Tags: boto3

I tried to run a program with boto3.  It says No module named 'boto3'.
I typed "pip show boto3"
it gave a bunch of info including where it was
"L:\program files\python3\lib\site-packages"
I then typed "echo %PATH%" even though I thought with pip knowing where it is, didn't think I needed it but to be thorough I did it.

It shows that exact directory twice.  4th and last.
Not sure what to do.  Any help?

The only code you need to see is the first line of code.
import boto3

Showing what is Happening

[image: 1]

Comment: Please post the error as text, not images.

Comment: L:\Programming\Python3\Email>python3 email.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "L:\Programming\Python3\Email\email.py", line 1, in <module>
    import boto3
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'boto3'

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add code and data as text ([using code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.  See [mcve] on what code is required.

Comment: I did that.  <br/>The ONLY error is <br/>"Traceback (most recent call last): File "L:\Programming\Python3\Email\email.py", line 1, in <module> import boto3 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'boto3'".  <br/>There is ONLY 1 line of code needed. <br/> import boto3  <br/>

Answer (score 0):

Probably you may have multiple versions of python installed

Try below

```
python3 -m pip install boto3
```

Comment: I have never installed python 2.

Comment: you may have python 3.6, 3.7 and so on as well. Did you try the above command by the way?

Comment: Oh that is what you mean.  Yes, it is possible.  When I ran that command, I got "No module named pip" but when I ran "pip show boto3" it ran fine.  I am really confused.  How can I delete all the old versions?  Thanks for your help BTW.